# Remove an extra comma in a string

Tags: php, str-replace

My string is something like this

`22,31,30`

I want to remove `31,` from this string so it should becomes: `22,30`

I'm using this:

```
$string = '21,31,30';
$newstring = str_replace("31", "", $string);
echo $newstring = trim($newstring, ",");
```

But it echoes this: `21,,30`

Please help!

Comment: So just use `str_replace("31,", "", $string);` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will solve your first and last element problem too:
Demo : https://eval.in/86932

```
$string = '31,21,31,30,31';
$newstring = str_replace("31", "", $string);
$newstring =trim(str_replace(",,", ",", $newstring),',');
echo $newstring;
```

Comment: @user2854563 : it will replace any double comma occurrences from the string

Comment: One thing left unexplained, sorry, that while removing the `31,` I'm not sure if the word contains a comma next to it or not, it may be just `30` means NO comma at the end, so how to do this?

Comment: @user2854563 : I have edited my answer. It should solve your this issue :) Can you try this?

Comment: Thanks my friend, your code is simple and it works :)

Thanks for all others too, I've +1 all of you who have provided worthy knowledgeable answers.

Answer (score 2):

How about using an array to make this a little cleaner, portable and re-usable?

```
$string = "21,31,30";
$values = explode(",", $string);
$toRemove = '31';

$values = array_filter($values, function($v) use ($toRemove) {
    if ($v != $toRemove) {
        return true;
   }
});

$newString = implode(",", $values);
```

$newString now contains "21,30"

Comment: +1. Cleaner than mine. That's what you get when you stick 20 programmers in a room and give them the same problem - 20 different answers!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma in your `str_replace`. Try this

```
 $newstring = str_replace("31,", "", $string);
```

If you need to remove an arbitrary element, you could do this::

```
$string='21,31,30';
$array=explode(",",$string);
$index=1; //Will remove the 2nd element of the array;
array_splice($array, $index, 1);
$newstring=implode(",",$array);
```

Comment: One thing left unexplained, sorry, that while removing the `31,` I'm not sure if the word contains a comma next to it or not, it may be just `30` means NO comma at the end, so how to do this?

Comment: @user2854563 I think what I did will work, If you need to find an element, you can use `indexOf`

Answer (score 1):

`trim` only removes characters from the beginning or end of the string, not in the middle.

If you don't know whether there will be a comma after the number or not, and especially if you want to remove a bunch of numbers from a long list, you could try something like

```
$string = '21,31,30';
$newstring = str_replace("31", "", $string);
while (strpos($string,",,")
  $string = str_replace(",,",",",$string);
```

That is, you remove any numbers you need to remove, and then you replace any instances of ",," (double comma) with a single comma.  The `while` is in case you removed a bunch of numbers and ended up with three or four commas in a row.

Answer (score 1):

You will `have a problem` **if your value will be in the end of string** and you will use trim function. Try this:

```
$string = '44, 55, 31';
$array = explode(",", $string);

$resultArray = unset($array[array_search('31', $array)]);   //here you delete your 31

$resultstring = implode(",", $resultArray);    //here will be result string without 31
```

Answer (score 1):

This would let you remove any number from your string regardless of which position it's in.

```
$string = "21,14,15,67";
$remove = 14;
$new = array();
$arr = explode(",", $string);
foreach($arr as $val){
    if($val != $remove){
        $new[] = $val;
    }
}
$string = implode(",", $new);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $newstring = str_replace("31,", "", $string);
```

You missed comma out of what you want replacing!

Comment: if 31 is in the end of the string ?

Comment: One thing left unexplained, sorry, that while removing the `31,` I'm not sure if the word contains a comma next to it or not, it may be just `30` means NO comma at the end, so how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you be sure the string will have a comma next to it?  If so, then you can do the following:

```
$string = '21,31,30';
$newstring = str_replace("31", "", $string);
$newstring2 = str_replace(",,", "", $newstring);
echo $newstring2 = trim($newstring2, ",");
```

The above would work (though it is not elegant) - it will make sure that if there is a comma around the 31, it will remove it.  It would, however, also remove any empty items such as "21,,30" - after the replace it would be "21,30".

Comment: One thing left unexplained, sorry, that while removing the `31,` I'm not sure if the word contains a comma next to it or not, it may be just `30` means NO comma at the end, so how to do this?